# Change the Title and Description of a react application in production

Tags: reactjs, netlify

When I created my application it was created by default with:

```
 <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
```

I have already changed to:

```
<meta
          name="description"
          content="New Description"
        />
```

However, when sharing the website link, it still continues with the first description. I've deployed again and nothing. I'm using netlify to deploy.
The same problem occurs with the title. I already checked the hosting and there is no description and title settings in them.

Comment: Could it be some caching issue? how are you deploying the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or [React Helemt](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) is an easy way to change document head (e.g. title & description ) on the go; check out their documentation for further reading ..

```
<Helmet>
  <title>My Title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Helmet application" />
</Helmet>
```